# Vue.js 'props' is working in the template, but undefined in methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a chile vue component and a property is passed as `'initial_features'`.

```
<child-component :initial_features="features"></child-component>
```

The code of my child component is:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col">
                {{ initial_features }} //this prop is working here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['initial_features'],
        data() {
            return {
                features: this.initial_features, //undefined
            }
        },
        methods: {},
        computed: {},
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.initial_features); //output is undefined here
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have written this type of code many times but this time I am not getting the expected result. The props should work in the data or mounted section. Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: make `features: null` inside your data and use `created` function to copy it to your features. :)

Comment: Not needed. You can use props to init `data`

Comment: I tried both but got `undefined`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code so only explanation is `features` passed as prop into your child component is 'undefined' when your child component is created (so `mounted` prints `undefined` and `data` is initialized with `undefined`) and later changed to something else by parent (maybe some Ajax loading?) so template renders new value. Why don't you use prop directly ?

Comment: I need to modify the props value and update them later. So I have defined another property in data. And shouldn't the data property be updated when the prop is updated after loading? But in the vue devtool, the property `features` is still undefined while the template is loaded correctly.

Comment: what about `data(vm){ return{features: vm.initial_features,};}`?

Comment: There si too much I don't know about your code (for example what type is `initial_features` prop and whats happening in parent component) but `data` function is called only once when component is created so if prop is updated later, it has no effect on `features` in `data` unless your passing object/array and updating that object/array instead of replacing it (which is not the case here because initial value is `undefined`). Add the code of parent and more details..

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it might be a case of data race condition.

"Initial_features" must be updated in the consumer of the component after the component is loaded, therefore, the data is set to undefined initially, you can always put a watch on initial_features and assign the data.features to the new value of initial_features.

If you want the data to track/update the prop consider the v-model property on your component [here is more info](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)